# Как безымянная функция в методе из компонента получает переменную?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ссылка на пример, по которому есть вопросы - https://jsfiddle.net/jom80eaw/

Мне не понятно, как безымянная функция в методе `addFriend` из компонента `FriendContainer` получает аргумент `friend`?

```
    var FriendContainer = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          name: 'Tyler McGinnis',
          friends: ['Jake Lingwall', 'Murphy Randall', 'Merrick Christensen']
        }
      },
      addFriend: function(friend) {
        this.setState({
          friends: this.state.friends.concat([friend])
        });
      },
      render: function(){
        return (
          <div>
            <h3> Name: {this.state.name} </h3>
            <AddFriend addNew={this.addFriend} />
            <ShowList names={this.state.friends} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    });

    var AddFriend = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          newFriend: ''
        }
      },
      updateNewFriend: function(e){
        this.setState({
          newFriend: e.target.value
        });
      },
      handleAddNew: function(){
        this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);
        this.setState({
          newFriend: ''
        });
      },
      render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.newFriend} onChange={this.updateNewFriend} />
              <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}>Add Friend</button>
            </div>
        );
      }
    });


    var ShowList = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var listItems = this.props.names.map(function(friend) {
          return <li> {friend} </li>;
        });
        return (
           <div>
            <h3> Friends </h3>
            <ul>
              {listItems}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })

    ReactDOM.render(
      <FriendContainer />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

В отдельности работа компонента `AddFriend`, который отвечает за добавление нового "друга", вроде бы понятна, но как он передает значение этого нового "друга" в функцию, которая в методе.

UPD: добавил весь код

Comment: **Минимальный** пример кода, описывающего проблему должен быть в самом вопросе. Ссылки могут служить только **дополнением**:

Comment: тут связываем функции `<AddFriend addNew={this.addFriend} />` тут вызываем и передаем `this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
<AddFriend addNew={this.addFriend} />
```

вы передаете метод `addFriend` как функцию обратного вызова компоненту `AddFriend`. Этот компонент вызывает переданный метод в обработчике действия по клику на кнопку, *передавая строку с именем пользователя*, которого нужно добавить:

```
var AddFriend = React.createClass({
    // ...
    handleAddNew: function(){
        // Вот код, передающий аргумент.
        this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

Comment: и все это в конце вешается на обработку клика кнопки :-) `<button onClick={this.handleAddNew}>Add Friend</button>`

Comment: @Grundy, именно так я и сказал: `вызывает переданный метод в обработчике действия по клику на кнопку`

Comment: не выделено, и не заметно :-D

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.